# Return status for PATCH call on locked record with no changes

Tags: rest, http-status-code-403, http-patch, http-status-code-409

I have a RESTful API that contains a typical PATCH call that allows fields to be updated under various conditions. Under some conditions (a particular status or combination of values), changes are "locked out" of a record. If a user makes a PATCH request to said record but the PATCH would not result in any changes being made (i.e. setting a field value to the same thing it already is), what status should the request return?

For example, I have a record

```
{
  _id: 12345,
  name: 'John Doe',
  age: 34,
  status: 'locked'
}
```

and I make a call

```
PATCH /users/12345
{
  age: 34
}
```

Since the status of the record is 'locked', no changes should be allowed. However, since the PATCH body states that the age value should be set to 34 which is what the value of age for that record already is, even if the record weren't locked, the request would result in no changes.

Should the request return 200 because the result of the PATCH is what the user requested in the first place or one of the 4xx codes (400, 403, or even 409) because the operation is being attempted on a "locked" record?

Comment: First, which media-type do you want to use for patching? The two common ones using JSON and PATCH are [JSON Patch](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6902) and [JSON Merge Patch](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7386). The latter one is probably the closest one to your approach, which is based on default rules to apply changes to the actual target resource. It i.e. states `If the target does contain the member, the value is replaced.` which is pretty straight forward IMO.

Comment: In regards to which status code to use you can check the [Patch specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789#section-2.2) that gives some hints on when to use which status code

Answer (score 0):

> Should the request return 200 because the result of the PATCH is what the user requested in the first place or one of the 4xx codes (400, 403, or even 409) because the operation is being attempted on a "locked" record?

REST is the architectural style of the HTTP application.  Caching is *very* important in REST.  The semantics of caching in HTTP are described by RFC 7234.  In particular, [cache invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) is described.

> A cache MUST invalidate the effective Request URI (Section 5.5 of [RFC7230]) as well as the URI(s) in the Location and Content-Location response header fields (if present) when a non-error status code is received in response to an unsafe request method.

So one way to consider this question: if the client has a representation of the resource in cache, do you want to force the client to invalidate the cached entries and refetch?

Another thing you may want to consider is whether or not your locking semantics align with those described by the [WebDAV specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-6.1); if they do, then returning [423 Locked](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.3) may be sensible.